# How fast does a sensor cool down sufficiently after a long exposure?

Tags: sensor, long-exposure

If I am taking long exposures for star trails how long should I wait between exposures to allow the sensor to cool down?

Comment: This is going to depend somewhat on the ambient temperature, a good answer would provide values for different temperature ranges.

Comment: i'd think gaps between exposures will leave gaps in the trails.

Comment: @ths I assume the intention is to have individual long exposures, not a stacked one.

Comment: @mattdm i interpreted the original "two sub in long exposure" as stacked. but who knows...

Comment: I've not used it, but StarStaX claims to be helpful in filling in the gaps in star trails from multiple exposures - http://www.markus-enzweiler.de/StarStaX/StarStaX.html

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the camera, you can read the sensor temperature from makernotes using [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool).
See, for example, Olympus tag 0x1007 [here](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/Olympus.html).
ths is right: intervals between exposures may leave gaps.